# Python Regex for only first match and ignore other matches

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to define a regex in python to match following string:

```
prefix:long-name
```

inside the example text:

```
prefix:long-name
asdd prefix:long-name asddasd
asdd prefix:long-name;
 prefix:long-name
prefix:long-name:other-prefix:long-name:long-name
prefix:long-name
```

But it should not match at following string:

```
prefix:long-name:other-prefix:long-name:long-name
```

I tried following regex with match-groups, but it doesn't work properly:

```
([^;\{\}\s\*\+\'"]+)(:)([^;\{\}\s\*\+\'"]+)
```

The problem is, that the regex would match both mentioned strings.

[See Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UD7ZnF/3)

At the end of the string could be line-ending, but it could be one of `[\s\{\}\;]` as well.

Does someone has an tip?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is at the end of the string, if not file-ending or line-ending?

Comment: I updated my post. It could be [\s\{\{\;] .

Comment: Why do you have `{` twice in your character class? or do you mean the literal string `[\s{{;]`? or just `\s{{;`? it's not clear...

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post with more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using the following pattern:

```
(?<!\S)[^\s:]+:[^\s:]+(?!\S)
```

Sample script:

```
inp = "asdd prefix:long-name asddasd prefix:long-name:other-prefix:long-name:long-name"
matches = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[^\s:]+:[^\s:]+(?!\S)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints only the short match:

```
['prefix:long-name']
```

Comment: It doesn't match. E.g. `abc:def:ghi:jkl` would match the `ghi:jkl`, but it shouldn't.

Comment: [It doesn't match, abc:def:ghi:jkl, check this demo](https://rextester.com/QUUJ30440).

Comment: You have an error. Most probably it's copy & paste based. You've forgotten the `^` and `$` in your pattern above but used it in the sample script! Also it might be better to use regex101.com instead of rextester.com!

Comment: @csabinho Yes, you are right.  I only used Rextester to show you working Python code, otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: regex101.com has a Python mode as well. So the only difference is that you can't use custom code on regex101.com.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It doesn't fit my requirements. See https://regex101.com/r/UD7ZnF/2.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It doesn't work properly. See https://regex101.com/r/UD7ZnF/6. It should not match the whole line, only `prefix:long-name`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Now, it works. See https://regex101.com/r/UD7ZnF/8. I gonna to mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the requirements with `lookahead` and `lookbehind`-assertion with following regex pattern:

`(?:^|(?<=[\s\{\}\;]))([^;{}\s\*\+\'\"\:\/]+)(:)([^;{}\s\*\+\'\"\:\/]+)(?:$|(?=[\s\{\}\;]))`

[See Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UD7ZnF/5) for an example.

Comment: See my answer for a possibly better way.  You can just use a single negative lookahead to rule out long matches.